# Fix a table thead

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress

I have this [page](http://birsmatt.ch/wohnungen-en/) (the Website is built using **Wordpress**) with a table and i am trying to fix the `thead` using this `<script>`:

```
<script>
document.getElementById("wrap").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate;
});
</script>
```

without results.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this.

```js
<script>
document.getElementById("wrap").addEventListener("scroll", function() {
//var translate = "translate(0," + this.scrollTop + "px)";
this.querySelector("thead").style.transform = translate(0,this.scrollTop+"px");
});
</script>
```